# Excel 2013 - select a date range and filted by agent

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

Bit of a tricky problem: I need to extract data from my table based on a date range and also filtered by agent. E.g I need to know the total for `agent2` between `03/01/2017` and `05/01/2017`.

Using `=SUMIFS(B2:B366,A2:A366,">="&I11,A2:A366,"<="&I12)` (`I11` and `I12` are where I input dates from/till) I can get the total for a single agent for a certain date range but I need to be able to select agent in the same way as dates.

Filtering using the table isn't an option as the output needs to be on a separate reporting sheet.

Is this even possible? :S Any help greatfully recieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the agent in I13 (e.g. "agent 3"), then this formula will get the sum for a particular agent:

`=SUMIFS(INDEX(B2:D366,,MATCH(I13,B1:E1,0)),A2:A366,">="&I11,A2:A366,"<="&I12)`

Here the INDEX() returns one column of the array.  That column is the one where the column heading matches the agent you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your SUMIFS formula to only include the value from a particular column by using the OFFSET function.

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(A2:A366,0,I13,,1),A2:A366,">="&I11,A2:A366,"<="&I12)
```

The OFFSET function allows you to select the column that is "N" columns to the right of column A, where "N" is the agent number (entered on cell I13).